# Source for Kissing Dropped Sefer

Tags: sources-mekorot, jewish-books, kissing

Is there any source for the common practice of kissing a dropped sefer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Sefer Chasidim 923](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41862&st=&pgnum=421&hilite=) says that if 2 Seforim fell on the ground, one should pick up both Seforim prior to kissing the first one.

[Aruch Hashulchan Yore Deah 282:11](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14244&st=&pgnum=366) also mentions kissing a Sefer that fell on the floor.